# Use CakePHP 3 Internationalization in Controller

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In a controller, I need to return translated message in an Ajax json response as:

```
$body['message'] = __("Duplicated");
$this->response->body(json_encode($body));
$this->response->statusCode(202);
$this->response->type('json');
return $this->response;
```

But the translation is not looked up.  However, in a template, I am able to get this working:

```
<?= __("Duplicated");?>
```

I know I can use the Ajax layout and write a template, but in this case the message body is very short, I need to return a Status Code other than 200.  How can I do this in a controller in CakePHP 3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a CakePHP bug (Not a bug, see comments below).  I have in app.php

```
'App' => [
...
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
...
]
```

and in AppController::beforeRender(), According to http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#changing-the-locale-at-runtime I could override with this (but in fact that does not work):

```
I18n::locale('zh');
```

When I change config/app.php to

```
'App' => [
...
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'zh'),
...
]
```

It works.

Comment: `beforeRender` happens _after_ the controller action has run, and _before_ the view is being rendered. So things are working as intended. **[http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake\Controller\Controller::beforeRender](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake\Controller\Controller::beforeRender)**